# PHP Why my 'if' statement always gives TRUE?

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I have been making stuff in PHP for a while, everything is always fine. But today I don't get this statement. Why is it always true?

```
if ($action != 1 || $action != 2) echo true; // TRUE for 0, 1, 2, 3
```

But the reverse logic

```
if ($action == 1 || $action == 2) echo true; // FALSE for 0, 3 TRUE for 1, 2
```

The first expression blows my mind. I guess I don't understand something very very basic, not in PHP but in the Universe, so I don't get it here. I thought that `if (FALSE || TRUE) == FALSE`, but it isn't a case for second example. It works as expected.

So, where is the answer how to say that: "If the variable is not 1 OR 2 - echo true". I don't understand why my `if ($var != 1 OR $var != 2) echo true;` doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: `false || true == true`. Your first condition *can't* be `false`.

Comment: `false || true` is true. That's the point of `||`, to be true if either argument is true.

Comment: *"If action is not 1 or is not 2"* – `$action` cannot be 1 *and* 2 at the same time, it's always *not* going to be one or the other.

Comment: For what value would you expect that first `if` to *ever* be false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negation of `($action != 1 || $action != 2)` is `($action == 1 && $action == 2)`. You can see for yourself that the latter is always false because variable can not be both 1 and 2 at the same time. Therefore the original condition is bound to be always true.

Answer (score 1):

It is working as it has to work. See the doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

`$a || $b` returns TRUE if **either** $a or $b is **TRUE**.

If you try like this, hope it will make sense, see the comment on every line

```
$action = 0;
var_dump($action != 1 || $action != 2); //here (true || true)
$action = 1;
var_dump($action != 1 || $action != 2); //here (false || true)
$action = 2;
var_dump($action != 1 || $action != 2); //here (true || false)
$action = 3;
var_dump($action != 1 || $action != 2); //here (true || true)
```

Comment: if ($var != 1 || $var != 2) echo true;
let say my $var is 3. 3 != 1 and 3 != 2. Two FALSE, so why the example is  still giving me true?

Comment: it'll also return `true` because (NULL != 1 || NULL!= 2) so that is (true || true) means `true`. But with some notice. **E_NOTICE :Undefined variable: var** make sense?  @mevsme

Comment: @mevsme because for  `and` TRUE, if both $a and $b are TRUE. For your condtion ` 3. 3 != 1 ` returns `true` and 3 != 2 returns `true`, So finaly `(true and true)` makes `true` as intended

Answer (score 1):

Condition OR will search for first TRUE result, your code will give TRUE all the time as any value will be even not 1 or 2. 
From you example if `$action = 1` then the condition `$action != 2` will give true, also if `$action = 2` then `$action != 1` will give TRUE.

For (If the variable is not 1 OR 2 - echo true) use this:

```
if(!in_array($action, array(1,2)) echo "true";
```

**EDIT:**
You can also check it like this:

```
if(!($action == 1 || $action == 2)) echo "true";
```

Comment: I would stick with this one ````if ($action != 2 && $action != 1) echo true;````

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($action == 2 || $action == 1) echo true; // FALSE for 0, 3 TRUE for 1, 2
```

Works as intended. Its basically "echo true if $action is either 1 or 2".

Comment: sure it is. The question is not about this statement.